# Is Qt Jambi dead?

Tags: java, swing, qt, qt-jambi

I know they announced in February that it was going to transition to a community-developed model over the next year... but right now, I can't find it on their website, at all, let alone version 4.5 that was supposed to be released this month.

I am about to embark on the GUI portion of a major project, and while I had considered using Qt Jambi, I am hesitant to create a major dependency on a product that has apparently been abandoned. Does anyone know the real status of this? Should I give up and use Swing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [mailing list for Jambi](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-jambi-interest/) that appears to still be active. You can view some recent posts about this topic in the [archives](http://lists.trolltech.com/pipermail/qt-jambi-interest/2009-March/thread.html). There is one response that appears to be from a trolltech employee about the future of Jambi but It doesn't really seem to say much more than their press release does.

> Tue Mar 10 14:37:29 CET 2009:
>
> We are hoping that a community of contributors will develop for the
> coming year, and will try to help make that happen. After that year has
> gone by, neither of us will be able to spend time on this project at
> work. But if there is a thriving community at that point, I wouldn't
> expect either of us to disappear completely either :-)
>
> We have spent some time on this
> project, and we definitely wish to see
> it succeed out in the wild. But, as
> you say, we cannot commit to  anything
> beyond what we have spare time for.
>
> A year is a long time in terms of
> spare time, so right now I'll only say
> that I hope there's still interest in
> a year, and I hope I get the  chance
> to help out. :-)
>
> -- Eskil

There is another post where they mention that they are still expecting a release soon. The latest code can be found [here](ftp://ftp.qtsoftware.com/qtjambi/source/).

Answer (score 0):

There are very recent commits at the activities page of their git repository.

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-jambi/qtjambi-community/activities

Comment: My ticket was updated October 2015. No QtJambi 5 for Qt5 though :(